# SQL Exercise - Can't seem to solve this

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm pretty new to writing SQL queries manually, and I have an exercise which I can't seem to solve.

I understand the tools that are needed to solve this, but I simply can't come up with a solution.

Can you help me understand how to solve this in a way that'll allow me solve similar exercises in the future?

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  Eid SERIAL primary key,
  Ename character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  salary integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Project (
  Pid SERIAL primary key,
  Pname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  requiredWorkers integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE workson (
  Eid integer references Employee(eid),
  Pid integer references Project(pid),
  Primary Key (Eid,Pid)
);
```

Exercise:

Several projects may have the same name (yet different Pids). Return the
eids of employees for which all projects on which they work have precisely
the same name. Only return employees who work on at least one project.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're supposed to return the name of an employee who works on *only* one project. (If an employee works on only one project, all of those projects have the same name.) To clearly exclude such employees, I'd expect *Only return employees who work on at least one project* to read *Only return employees who work on at least two projects* instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use for example `NOT EXISTS`

```
select distinct w1.eid
from Project p1
join workson w1 on p1.pid = w1.pid
where not exists(
  select 1
  from Project p2
  join workson w2 on p2.pid = w2.pid
  where w1.eid = w2.eid and p2.pname != p1.pname
)
```

and another solution is to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
select w.eid
from Project p
join workson w on p.pid = w.pid
group by w.eid
having count(distinct p.pname) = 1
```